# Match a route only if a route param matches an enumeration value

Tags: react-router

I have two routes in react router which are of same depth.

/:category/:period
/:category/:attribute

To differentiate between one and two, I want to match the first route only if the period is one of (year|quarter|month). How do I write the route?

I tried /:category/(year|month|quarter):period

But does not seem to work. What would be the right regex so that the route is captured only when period is one of year, month, quarter. And that value is available as a route param - period. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following route works:
/:category/:period(year|month|quarter)